# How to pass data to php-fpm

Tags: php, sockets, rust

I would like to ask you for help because I have a question about unix sockets in rust. I want to try to connect to the `php-fpm` service in rust (I'm on a Linux machine), and I think I can connect, but how can I interact with it? Let me explain what I mean, this is my code:

```
use std::os::unix::net::{UnixStream};
use std::io::{Read, Write};

fn main() {
    let socket_path = "/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock";

    let mut socket = match UnixStream::connect(socket_path) {
        Ok(sock) => sock,
        Err(e) => {
            println!("Couldn't connect: {e:?}");
            return
        }
    };
}
```

And the code above works perfectly. But how can I start using it? I mean maybe execute php files from the socket, get their output or the headers that the program returns and stuff like that. I've been looking for ways to do it for days, but I can't find how, I've found libraries to do it but they haven't worked for me, [like this library](https://crates.io/crates/fastcgi-client) (Just as an example, with that library I didn't know how to get the "headers" of the program). Do you know any way to start using that socket and start working with php files from the same socket? Thanks in advance.

### Edit

I have been reading [the link](https://web.archive.org/web/20160119141816/http://www.fastcgi.com/drupal/node/6?q=node%2F22) that [Jmb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5397009/jmb) passed me and I think I understand more how it works, but now I have a question very similar to the main one. How do I pass the data? For example, how do I tell the socket that I want to send a *[FCGI_BEGIN_REQUEST](https://web.archive.org/web/20160119141816/http://www.fastcgi.com/drupal/node/6?q=node%2F22#S5.1)* because, if I understand correctly, the web server is the one that has to send that, not the socket, and I think that with that I could start with the rest of the request. I'm asking the "how" to know how it should be done, because, for example, I don't think it should be done like this:

```
socket.write(b"FCGI_BEGIN_REQUEST")
```

That's just a very vague example, but I think it reflects what I'm talking about. I hope you can help me and tell me how I should write the data through the socket. And finally, if I am misunderstanding something about how they work, I would appreciate it if you also tell me so I can correct my question.

Comment: It's not really clear what you're trying to do, or why. If you want to run the PHP files, why not make HTTP requests to them in the normal way via the webserver?

Comment: @ADyson Oh, I'm doing that for many reasons, just to name a few. I would like to understand the process behind a web server when I am using php, and finally I would like to understand more about Unix sockets :D.

Comment: So Rust is the client side, PHP is the server side, and you wanna communicate (to run the cgi service? ) between these two processes through UNIX domain socket, is this what you want?

Comment: @SteveLau Yes, that is what I would like to do, but I haven't found a way to pass the data to it, and I don't want to do it with libraries specifically for FASTCGI because none of them have worked for me.

Comment: What does your PHP code look like? If your code does not work, which kind of error have you got? And in your client-side code, I don't see any read/write operations, would you like to provide a complete code snippet where you have tried to interact with your server?

Comment: The fastcgi protocol is specified [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160119141816/http://www.fastcgi.com/drupal/node/6?q=node%2F22). If you don't want to use an existing library, you will need to implement it yourself through your `socket`.

Comment: @SteveLau I think you have not understood, I am just asking about that, what I would like to know is just how to pass the data to the server

Comment: @Jmb I already edited my question with more information on the link you gave me

Comment: `the web server is the one that has to send that`...yes but in this case I think you're basically taking the place of the webserver, which is normally the client of the FCGI component. Normally, if my understanding is correct, the webserver gets a request from a browser (or other HTTP client), and then passes it onto the CGI component if it needs to, then waits for a response from CGI, then passes that back to the browser.

Comment: @ADyson Yes, in this case I am the web server, what I am looking for is the way to pass the data through the socket to be able to make a complete request because I have not fully understood the way in which I should write the data in the socket

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastcgi protocol is specified [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160119141816/http://www.fastcgi.com/drupal/node/6?q=node%2F22). If you don't want to use an existing library, you will need to implement it yourself through your socket. FastCGI is a binary protocol, in which the messages are specified in [section 8](https://web.archive.org/web/20160119141816/http://www.fastcgi.com/drupal/node/6?q=node%2F22#S8) as if they were C structs. For example for `FCGI_BEGIN_REQUEST`, the relevant parts of the spec are:

```c
typedef struct {
    unsigned char version;
    unsigned char type;
    unsigned char requestIdB1;
    unsigned char requestIdB0;
    unsigned char contentLengthB1;
    unsigned char contentLengthB0;
    unsigned char paddingLength;
    unsigned char reserved;
} FCGI_Header;

#define FCGI_VERSION_1           1

#define FCGI_BEGIN_REQUEST       1

typedef struct {
    unsigned char roleB1;
    unsigned char roleB0;
    unsigned char flags;
    unsigned char reserved[5];
} FCGI_BeginRequestBody;

typedef struct {
    FCGI_Header header;
    FCGI_BeginRequestBody body;
} FCGI_BeginRequestRecord;

#define FCGI_RESPONDER  1
#define FCGI_AUTHORIZER 2
#define FCGI_FILTER     3
```

This means that an `FCGI_BEGIN_REQUEST` message should be sent as a 16-byte block of data like:

```
const FCGI_VERSION_1: u8    = 1;
const FCGI_BEGIN_REQUEST:u8 = 1;

const FCGI_RESPONDER: u16  = 1;
const FCGI_AUTHORIZER: u16 = 2;
const FCGI_FILTER: u16     = 3;

let requestId = 0x1234;    // Change for each request
let role = FCGI_RESPONDER;
let beginRequest = vec![
   // FCGI_Header
   FCGI_VERSION_1, FCGI_BEGIN_REQUEST, 
   (requestId >> 8) as u8, (requestId & 0xFF) as u8,
   0x00, 0x08, // This is the size of `FCGI_BeginRequestBody`
   0, 0,
   // FCGI_BeginRequestBody
   (role >> 8) as u8, (role & 0xFF) as u8,
   0, // Flags
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, // Reserved
];
socket.write_all (&beginRequest).unwrap();
```

The body of the request is typically sent using one or several `FCGI_STDIN` messages, i.e.:

```
let contentLength = data.len();
assert!(contentLength <= u16::MAX); // TODO: split the content if it is too large
let requestHeader = vec![
   FCGI_VERSION_1, FCGI_STDIN, 
   (requestId >> 8) as u8, (requestId & 0xFF) as u8,
   (contentLength >> 8) as u8, (contentLength & 0xFF) as u8,
   0, 0,
];
socket.write_all (&requestHeader).unwrap();
socket.write_all (&data).unwrap();
```

The [`fastcgi` crate](https://crates.io/crates/fastcgi) implements the application side of the protocol. You can look at its [source code](https://docs.rs/fastcgi/1.0.0/src/fastcgi/lib.rs.html) for inspiration on how to implement the webserver side.

Comment: Thank you very much, this type of response was what I was looking for, only I have a doubt in your example, the `data` variable, what value should it have?

Comment: @New1 the value of `data` is application-dependent. Typically it would be used by a web server to pass on the contents of a `POST` request, like in the [second example](https://web.archive.org/web/20160119141816/http://www.fastcgi.com/drupal/node/6?q=node%2F22#SB) in the spec.

Comment: @New1 regarding `data`, there was a typo in my answer: the data should be sent as part of a `FCGI_STDIN` message, _not_ a second `FCGI_BEGIN_REQUEST`

Comment: oh ok thanks for saying that