# How to get the output of programs with FastCGI

Tags: rust, fastcgi

I would like to ask you for help with a question I have working with the [FastCGI](https://web.archive.org/web/20160119141816/http://www.fastcgi.com/drupal/node/6?q=node%2F22) protocol in Rust.

This is my code (I have this code thanks to the answers of my past questions related to this topic, which are [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73902548/how-to-pass-data-to-php-fpm-socket-in-rust-using-sockets) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73923077/how-to-write-fcgi-params-in-rust-using-unix-sockets/73923798#73923798)):

```
#![allow(non_snake_case)]
#![allow(unused_must_use)]
use std::os::unix::net::{UnixStream};
use std::io::{Read, Write};

fn main() {
    const FCGI_VERSION_1: u8    = 1;
    const FCGI_BEGIN_REQUEST:u8 = 1;
    const FCGI_END_REQUEST: u8 = 3;

    const FCGI_RESPONDER: u16  = 1;

    const FCGI_PARAMS: u8 = 4;

    const FCGI_GET_VALUES: u8 = 9;

    let socket_path = "/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock";

    let mut socket = match UnixStream::connect(socket_path) {
        Ok(sock) => sock,
        Err(e) => {
            println!("Couldn't connect: {e:?}");
            return
        }
    };

    let requestId: u16 = 1;

    let role: u16 = FCGI_RESPONDER;

    let beginRequest = vec![
       // FCGI_Header
       FCGI_VERSION_1, FCGI_BEGIN_REQUEST,
       (requestId >> 8) as u8, (requestId & 0xFF) as u8,
       0x00, 0x08, // This is the size of `FCGI_BeginRequestBody`
       0, 0,
       // FCGI_BeginRequestBody
       (role >> 8) as u8, (role & 0xFF) as u8,
       0, // Flags
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, // Reserved
    ];

    socket.write_all(&beginRequest).unwrap();

    let data = vec![
        (100) as u8,
    ];

    let contentLength = data.len();

    assert!(contentLength <= usize::MAX);

    let requestHeader = vec![
       FCGI_VERSION_1, FCGI_BEGIN_REQUEST,
       (requestId >> 8) as u8, (requestId & 0xFF) as u8,
       (contentLength >> 8) as u8, (contentLength & 0xFF) as u8,
      0, 0,
    ];

    socket.write_all(&requestHeader).unwrap();


    let param_name = "SCRIPT_FILENAME".as_bytes();
    let param_value = "index.php".as_bytes();
    let lengths = [ param_name.len() as u8, param_value.len() as u8 ];
    socket.write_all (&lengths).unwrap();
    socket.write_all (param_name).unwrap();
    socket.write_all (param_value).unwrap();

    let mut response = String::new();

    socket.read_to_string(&mut response);

    print!("response: {}", response);
}
```

That code starts a request and write the parameter `SCRIPT_FILENAME` in the socket. I think that code works fine, and when executing the program, the console shows me this:

```
response: DX-Powered-By: PHP/8.1.11
Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

So I am assuming that FastCGI is not executing the PHP file that I am passing it, so what I did was try to find how to execute the files, or execute the request in the [FastCGI specification index](https://web.archive.org/web/20160119141816/http://www.fastcgi.com/drupal/node/6?q=node%2F22#S5.5).

But I didn't understand how to do it. So how can I get the output of the php file that I am passing to it? What am I omitting? I'd like to clarify that I'm pretty new to this FastCGI thing and I don't have any experience with binary protocols, so I'm really sorry if I'm missing something that seems obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove your second `FCGI_BEGIN_REQUEST` message and add a `FCGI_STDIN` message *after* the `FCGI_PARAMS` message (use `contentLength=0` if you don't have any `POST` data to send). Then use [`read_exact`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.54.0/std/io/trait.Read.html#method.read_exact) to read the header of the response, extract its content length and `read_exact` again to get contents of the response:

```
use std::os::unix::net::{UnixStream};
use std::io::{Read, Write};

fn main() {
    const FCGI_VERSION_1: u8    = 1;

    const FCGI_BEGIN_REQUEST:u8 = 1;
    const FCGI_END_REQUEST: u8  = 3;
    const FCGI_STDIN: u8        = 5;
    const FCGI_STDOUT: u8       = 6;

    const FCGI_RESPONDER: u16  = 1;

    const FCGI_PARAMS: u8 = 4;

    const FCGI_GET_VALUES: u8 = 9;

    let socket_path = "/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock";

    let mut socket = match UnixStream::connect(socket_path) {
        Ok(sock) => sock,
        Err(e) => {
            println!("Couldn't connect: {e:?}");
            return
        }
    };

    let requestId: u16 = 1;
    let role: u16 = FCGI_RESPONDER;
    let beginRequest = vec![
       // FCGI_Header
       FCGI_VERSION_1, FCGI_BEGIN_REQUEST, 
       (requestId >> 8) as u8, (requestId & 0xFF) as u8,
       0x00, 0x08, // This is the size of `FCGI_BeginRequestBody`
       0, 0,
       // FCGI_BeginRequestBody
       (role >> 8) as u8, (role & 0xFF) as u8,
       0, // Flags
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, // Reserved
    ];
    socket.write_all(&beginRequest).unwrap();

    let param_name = "SCRIPT_FILENAME".as_bytes();
    let param_value = "index.php".as_bytes();
    let lengths = [ param_name.len() as u8, param_value.len() as u8 ];
    socket.write_all (&lengths).unwrap();
    socket.write_all (param_name).unwrap();
    socket.write_all (param_value).unwrap();

    let requestHeader = vec![
       FCGI_VERSION_1, FCGI_STDIN,
       (requestId >> 8) as u8, (requestId & 0xFF) as u8,
       0, 0,
       0, 0,
    ];
    socket.write_all(&requestHeader).unwrap();

    let mut responseHeader = [0u8; 8];
    socket.read_exact (&mut responseHeader).unwrap();
    assert!(responseHeader[1] == FCGI_STDOUT);  // TODO: proper handling of message type
    let responseLength = ((responseHeader[4] as usize) << 8) | (responseHeader[5] as usize);
    let mut responseBody = Vec::new();
    responseBody.resize (responseLength, 0);
    socket.read_exact (&mut responseBody).unwrap();
    println!("{responseBody:?}");
}
```

Notes:

- The response may be split into several `FCGI_STDOUT` messages, so you will need a loop to reassemble them all.
- php may send other messages types than `FCGI_STDOUT`, so you will need to add proper handling of the message type in place of the `assert` I've used.