# How to read all output from a FastCGI request?

Tags: php, rust, fastcgi

I am trying to make a request to PHP files from Rust using the [FastCGI](https://web.archive.org/web/20160119141816/http://www.fastcgi.com/drupal/node/6?q=node%2F22#S1) protocol. I have this code thanks to the answer of [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73930911/how-to-get-the-output-of-programs-with-fastcgi-in-rust/73932340#73932340):

```rust
use std::os::unix::net::{UnixStream};
use std::io::{Read, Write};
use std::str;

fn main() {
    const FCGI_VERSION_1: u8    = 1;

    const FCGI_BEGIN_REQUEST:u8 = 1;
    const FCGI_END_REQUEST: u8  = 3;
    const FCGI_STDIN: u8        = 5;
    const FCGI_STDOUT: u8       = 6;

    const FCGI_RESPONDER: u16  = 1;

    const FCGI_PARAMS: u8 = 4;

    const FCGI_GET_VALUES: u8 = 9;

    let socket_path = "/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock";

    let mut socket = match UnixStream::connect(socket_path) {
        Ok(sock) => sock,
        Err(e) => {
            println!("Couldn't connect: {e:?}");
            return
        }
    };

    let requestId: u16 = 1;
    let role: u16 = FCGI_RESPONDER;
    let beginRequest = vec![
       // FCGI_Header
       FCGI_VERSION_1, FCGI_BEGIN_REQUEST,
       (requestId >> 8) as u8, (requestId & 0xFF) as u8,
       0x00, 0x08, // This is the size of `FCGI_BeginRequestBody`
       0, 0,
       // FCGI_BeginRequestBody
       (role >> 8) as u8, (role & 0xFF) as u8,
       0, // Flags
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, // Reserved
    ];
    socket.write_all(&beginRequest).unwrap();

    let param_name = "SCRIPT_FILENAME".as_bytes();
    let param_value = "/var/www/html/index.php".as_bytes();
    let lengths = [ param_name.len() as u8, param_value.len() as u8 ];
    socket.write_all (&lengths).unwrap();
    socket.write_all (param_name).unwrap();
    socket.write_all (param_value).unwrap();

    let requestHeader = vec![
       FCGI_VERSION_1, FCGI_STDIN,
       (requestId >> 8) as u8, (requestId & 0xFF) as u8,
       0, 0,
       0, 0,
    ];
    socket.write_all(&requestHeader).unwrap();

    let mut responseHeader = [0u8; 8];
    socket.read_exact (&mut responseHeader).unwrap();
    assert!(responseHeader[1] == FCGI_STDOUT);  // TODO: proper handling of message type
    let responseLength = ((responseHeader[4] as usize) << 8) | (responseHeader[5] as usize);
    let mut responseBody = Vec::new();
    responseBody.resize (responseLength, 0);
    socket.read_exact (&mut responseBody).unwrap();
    println!("{:?}", std::str::from_utf8(responseBody));
}
```

That code starts a request and then it writes the `SCRIPT_FILENAME` parameter, and then it reads the output of the PHP file. This is the PHP file:

```php
<?php

echo "First file";

?>
```

When I run the Rust file, this is what the console shows me:

```
Ok("X-Powered-By: PHP/8.1.11\r\nContent-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n\r\n")
```

The console does not show me the output of my program, so I imagine the problem may be what [Jmb said in the answer he gave me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73930911/how-to-get-the-output-of-programs-with-fastcgi-in-rust/73932340#73932340):

> The response may be split into several FCGI_STDOUT messages, so you will need a loop to reassemble them all.

Now that I see [example 3 of the FastCGI protocol specification](https://web.archive.org/web/20160119141816/http://www.fastcgi.com/drupal/node/6?q=node%2F22#SB) I realize that in that example the output of the program is still divided (or so I think). So how can I read all the output of my program? I know Jmb said that I needed a loop to do that, so how should I implement the loop? Or where? I'd like to clarify that I'm pretty new to this FastCGI thing and I don't have any experience with binary protocols, so I'm really sorry if I'm missing something that seems obvious.

Comment: Not strictly related, so please don't take this negatively. If you already have Apache or NGINX on the server to deliver PHP, then considering going through that as a regular HTTP request from Rust.  We looked at doing direct to fast-cgi (except from c#, not Rust) but determined the extra protection, logging, socket reuse/keep alive etc made more sense to go via the web server as a local HTTP request (with protections).  Having said that, I'm following as I want to see what the answer is!

Comment: @Robbie Oh yes, I understand you don't mean that in a negative way. This is what catches my attention because that is supposed to be the way in which nginx works, and since that is how several http servers work, I wanted to know how they worked at a "low level".

Comment: I do not know either rust or fastcgi protocol but, maybe, you should
use socket.read_to_end (or read_to_string if is better for your purpose) https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/io/trait.Read.html#method.read_to_end
instead of socket.read_exact this should read until the remote host close the connection (script execution end)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few issues with your code.

#### Issue #1

The last byte of an `FCGI_Record` is named `padding`. It says how many bytes should be skipped after that payload. You are setting it to 0 so it does not matter there, but when reading from the server you must skip so many bytes:

```
    let mut pad = vec![0; responseHeader[7] as usize];
    socket.read_exact (&mut pad).unwrap();
```

This explains that if you tried to do the read loop, you would be getting garbage instead of the `FCGI_END_REQUEST` frame.

#### Issue #2

The *params* part requires a header, but you are sending them raw.
You have to compute the full length of the serialized parameters and send the header before that:

```
    let params_len: u16 = (param_name.len() + param_value.len() + lengths.len()) as u16;
    let paramsRequest = vec![
       FCGI_VERSION_1, FCGI_PARAMS,
       (requestId >> 8) as u8, (requestId & 0xFF) as u8,
       (params_len >> 8) as u8, (params_len & 0xFF) as u8,
       0, 0,
    ];
    socket.write_all (&paramsRequest).unwrap();
```

#### Issue #3

I didn't find anywhere the minimum parameters required by `php-fpm`, but [skimming the source code](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/69eb38b4608bfd29239a16f01501d3af22104829/sapi/fpm/fpm/fpm_main.c#L1838), you need at least to add `REQUEST_METHOD`:

```
    let param1_name = "SCRIPT_FILENAME".as_bytes();
    let param1_value = "/var/www/html/index.php".as_bytes();
    let lengths1 = [ param1_name.len() as u8, param1_value.len() as u8 ];
    let params1_len: u16 = (param1_name.len() + param1_value.len() + lengths1.len()) as u16;

    let param2_name = b"REQUEST_METHOD";
    let param2_value = b"GET";
    let lengths2 = [ param2_name.len() as u8, param2_value.len() as u8 ];
    let params2_len: u16 = (param2_name.len() + param2_value.len() + lengths2.len()) as u16;

    let params_len = params1_len + params2_len;
    let paramsRequest = vec![
       FCGI_VERSION_1, FCGI_PARAMS,
       (requestId >> 8) as u8, (requestId & 0xFF) as u8,
       (params_len >> 8) as u8, (params_len & 0xFF) as u8,
       0, 0,
    ];
    socket.write_all (&paramsRequest).unwrap();
    socket.write_all (&lengths1).unwrap();
    socket.write_all (param1_name).unwrap();
    socket.write_all (param1_value).unwrap();
    socket.write_all (&lengths2).unwrap();
    socket.write_all (param2_name).unwrap();
    socket.write_all (param2_value).unwrap();
```

At this point I think you should consider writing proper types and serialization primitives for those things instead of raw byte arrays...

With these changes we already get the full output:

```
Ok("X-Powered-By: PHP/8.1.11\r\nContent-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n\r\nFirst file")
```

#### Issue #4

You should loop the read response code, concatenating any `FCGI_STDOUT` data, logging or ignoring other messages, maybe logging `FCGI_STDERR` messages, until you get a `FCGI_END_REQUEST`.

In this particular example the output is so short that it fits in a single message, but by not doing the loop you don't see the `FCGI_END_REQUEST`.

After the `FCGI_END_REQUEST`, depending on whether you used the `FCGI_KEEP_CONN` you will either close the socket or keep it opened to send a new request.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much for the answer, with that answer you answered many of the other questions I had.