# How can I remove the \n at the end of a line but keep the line breaks in a file? In FastCGI requests

Tags: php, rust, fastcgi

Currently the code that I have is in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73965913/how-to-read-all-output-from-a-fastcgi-request) (I don't know if it is necessary to add the code, although it is the same that I have in that question, but if you think I should add the code here tell me and I will do it)

Running my program with the code above I get this output:

> Ok("X-Powered-By: PHP/8.1.11\r\nContent-type: text/html;
> charset=UTF-8\r\n\r\nFirst file")

But the content of my PHP file is this:

```
<?php

echo "First file";

?>
```

Clearly in the output of the program that I show, the output of my PHP program is there, but it returns it to me like this

```
\r\n\r\nFirst file
```

So, the first thing I thought was to try to treat the output of my PHP program using regular expressions, for example, after "\r\n\r\n" it would return what I think would be the "output" of my file, and works. But there is a bug with that, if I have longer PHP files, like this for example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    
</body>
</html>
<?php

echo "PHP file";

header("Location: form.php");

?>
```

The output I get when executing the FastCGI request is this:

```
Ok("Status: 302 Found\r\nX-Powered-By: PHP/8.1.11\r\nLocation: form.php\r\nContent-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n\r\n<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang=\"en\">\n<head>\n    <meta charset=\"UTF-8\">\n    <meta http-equiv=\"X-UA-Compatible\" content=\"IE=edge\">\n    <meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0\">\n    <title>Document</title>\n</head>\n<body>\n    \n</body>\n</html>\nPHP file")
```

As you can see, after each newline I get a \n, but for example, if I want to show that in a web browser, that would not be a good idea, or at least the browser would not give the output I expect since there is lots of \n, and for obvious reasons I can't deal with them using regular expressions. So my question is, how can I remove the \n but still have the line breaks in my html code? Since an html file without line breaks would be unmaintainable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't posted your Rust code, but it seems like you're confused by the debug output. The literal character sequences `\n` (or `\r`, for that matter) are not in the response string, they are literal newlines and carriage returns (ASCII codes 10 and 13). When printing with `Debug`, Rust tries to make it easier for you to spot them by showing them as `\n`, just like they would appear in a string literal.

Consider this example:

```rust
fn main() {
    let text = "Hello\nWorld";
    println!("With Debug:");
    println!("{:?}", text);
    println!("With Display:");
    println!("{}", text);
}
```

[(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=369c2e51fcc89de17f27b33f84a2f483)

The output is:

```
With Debug:
"Hello\nWorld"
With Display:
Hello
World
```

---

On another note, `\r\n\r\n` separates HTTP headers from the response body (or more accurately, every header is followed by `\r\n`, and the end of headers is marked by another `\r\n`). If you want to parse separate parts of the HTTP response (status code, headers, body), I would suggest using a proper HTTP parser instead of regular expressions. Or, just return the response verbatim to the user - it seems like a well formed HTTP response.