# Should I use read_exact in this case? Rust

Tags: sockets, rust

I am trying to implement [FastCGI](https://web.archive.org/web/20160119141816/http://www.fastcgi.com/drupal/node/6?q=node%2F22) protocol in rust. And when I had a problem I asked a question here on stackoverflow ([the question is this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73930911/how-to-get-the-output-of-programs-with-fastcgi/73932340)). And as you can see the [answer to my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73930911/how-to-get-the-output-of-programs-with-fastcgi/73932340#73932340) says this:

> Then use [read_exact](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.54.0/std/io/trait.Read.html#method.read_exact) to read the header of the response, extract its
> content length and read_exact again to get contents of the response:

And I really had no problem with that. But since then, I've come across people (both online and in real life) who say something pretty similar to this:):

> Avoid the "exact" functions as they might
> silently swallow some stream content, see the docs.

So my question is. Should I use `read_exact` for my specific case? Are the people who said not to use `read_exact` right? Why should I occupy it or why should I **NOT** occupy it? If you need more context about my case in particular, everything is in my question that I passed at the beginning of this post

Comment: Can you point to a source saying not to use `read_exact`? At a glance I can't find anything discouraging its use. Its only caveat seems to be that the contents of the buffer are unspecified when it encounters an early EOF.

Comment: If you're calling it directly on an I/O resource like a socket or file, many small `read`/`read_exact` calls may be suboptimal. In that case you'd likely want to wrap it in a [`BufReader`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.BufReader.html) so that reads are batched. If you do wrap it in a `BufReader` and then unwrap it to get the original I/O resource, you *could* miss stream content that was "read-ahead" by the `BufReader` and still in its buffer (the docs mention this and other related cases). That's about the only way I can think to correlate `read_exact` with missing content.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure the people who discourage using `read_exact` are referring to Rust? Upon searching for this, I was only able to find people talking about other languages.

**It should be fine to use `read_exact`.**

To start off, we can see that it will never read more bytes than necessary in the [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Read.html#method.read_exact):

> If this function returns an error, it is unspecified how many bytes it has read, but it will never read more than would be necessary to completely fill the buffer.

The only information we lose by using `read_exact` is the exact number of bytes we read upon reaching an error and any [`ErrorKind::Interrupted`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Read.html#method.read_exact) errors. However, upon reading the documentation for interrupted errors we can see it states as follows.

> This operation was interrupted.
>
> Interrupted operations can typically be retried.

Unless you are explicitly using some library which states some additional action is required before continuing to read after an interrupted error, you can assume this action can be retried until either the bytes are read or an error indicating that reading is no longer possible occurs. If you are using `read_exact` on a generic `std::io::Read` input, it is safe to assume that the caller has handled this use case appropriatly.

You can also verify this is correct by reading the standard library implementation of `read_exact`. I have yet to see any major library choose to provide their own implementation for `read_exact`, but it is in theory possible. However, they should still adhere to the documentation for `read_exact` which yields the same conclusion as before.

```rust
pub trait Read {
    #[stable(feature = "read_exact", since = "1.6.0")]
    fn read_exact(&mut self, buf: &mut [u8]) -> Result<()> {
        default_read_exact(self, buf)
    }

    // etc...
}


pub(crate) fn default_read_exact<R: Read + ?Sized>(this: &mut R, mut buf: &mut [u8]) -> Result<()> {
    while !buf.is_empty() {
        match this.read(buf) {
            Ok(0) => break,
            Ok(n) => {
                let tmp = buf;
                buf = &mut tmp[n..];
            }
            Err(ref e) if e.kind() == ErrorKind::Interrupted => {}
            Err(e) => return Err(e),
        }
    }
    if !buf.is_empty() {
        Err(error::const_io_error!(ErrorKind::UnexpectedEof, "failed to fill whole buffer"))
    } else {
        Ok(())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is only one situation I'm aware of where `read_exact` may lose data, and that's if an error (other than `Interrupted`) occurs after it has started reading but before it reaches the requested amount. In that case the data that has already been read before the error is lost, but in most cases you wouldn't be able to do anything with that data anyway since it's incomplete and you would just handle the error itself instead.